# Python - Encoding Kamenicky (CP-895)

Tags: python, encoding, byte

I need read bytes from file and compare them with dictionary (encode from Kamenicky to CP1250). This code throws error "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str". Please do not mention "hardcoded" paths as they are here for testing purposes only. Please can you help me and tell me what is wrong in this Python code?

```
def Convert(file):
 kamenicky = bytes( {128 : 185, 
        129 : 252, 
        130 : 233, 
        131 : 239, 
        132 : 228, 
        133 : 192, 
        134 : 141, 
        135 : 232, 
        136 : 236, 
        137 : 189, 
        138 : 188, 
        139 : 237, 
        140 : 190, 
        141 : 229,
        142 : 181,
        143 : 178,
        144 : 186,
        145 : 158,
        146 : 142,
        147 : 244,
        148 : 246,
        149 : 211,
        150 : 249,
        151 : 218,
        152 : 253,
        153 : 214,
        154 : 220,
        155 : 138,
        156 : 188,
        157 : 221,
        158 : 216,
        159 : 157,
        160 : 225,
        161 : 237,
        162 : 243,
        163 : 250,
        164 : 242,
        165 : 210,
        166 : 217,
        167 : 212,
        168 : 154,
        169 : 248,
        170 : 224})
 out = ""
 with open("test.csv", 'rb') as f: 
    for byte in f.read():
        if byte in kamenicky:
            out += kamenicky[byte]
        else:
            out += byte

 w = open("new.csv", 'wb')
 w.write(out)
 w.close()
```

Almost same code WORKING in C#:

```
class Kamenicky
{
    Dictionary<byte, byte> kamenicky = new Dictionary<byte, byte> {
        {128, 185}, 
        {129, 252}, 
        {130, 233}, 
        {131, 239}, 
        {132, 228}, 
        {133, 192}, 
        {134, 141}, 
        {135, 232}, 
        {136, 236}, 
        {137, 189}, 
        {138, 188}, 
        {139, 237}, 
        {140, 190}, 
        {141, 229},
        {142, 181},
        {143, 178},
        {144, 186},
        {145, 158},
        {146, 142},
        {147, 244},
        {148, 246},
        {149, 211},
        {150, 249},
        {151, 218},
        {152, 253},
        {153, 214},
        {154, 220},
        {155, 138},
        {156, 188},
        {157, 221},
        {158, 216},
        {159, 157},
        {160, 225},
        {161, 237},
        {162, 243},
        {163, 250},
        {164, 242},
        {165, 210},
        {166, 217},
        {167, 212},
        {168, 154},
        {169, 248},
        {170, 224}
    };

    public void KamenickyToCP1250(string file)
    {
        List<Byte> temp = new List<byte>();
        byte[] ByteFile = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        foreach (byte BYTE in ByteFile)
        {
            if (kamenicky.ContainsKey(BYTE)) { temp.Add(kamenicky[BYTE]); continue; }
            temp.Add(BYTE);
        }

        File.Delete(file);
        File.WriteAllBytes(file, temp.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `byte` from a single-character string to an integer. One way to do it as follows:

```
 with open("test.csv", 'rb') as f: 
    for ch in f.read():
       byte = ord(ch)
       ...
```